# pugixml: Cannot get children/cannot iterate

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, pugixml

I am using [pugixml](https://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/access.html) for the first time and I am not able to correctly load a file into memory.

My XML test document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node>
</node>
```

I use following code to load the document and get the child:

```
pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load("test.xml");
if (result)
{
    Log(L"XML [%s] parsed without errors", L"test.xml");

    pugi::xml_node node = doc.child(L"node");
    if (node)
        Log(L"it works");
    else
        Log(L"it does not work");

    doc.save_file(L"test.xml");
}
else
{
    Log(L"XML [%s] parsed with errors", L"test.xml");
    Log(L"XML Error description: %s", result.description());
    Log(L"XML Error offset: %d", result.offset);
}
```

Output:

```
XML [test.xml] parsed without errors

it does not work
```

XML file after execution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

(When using doc.save_file function data are lost)

Compiler: MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Language: C++

Build:    UNICODE/x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of opening the file your code is parsing the string "test.xml".
Use `doc.load_file("test.xml")`.

`doc.load("test.xml")` did not return any errors because pugixml does not reject root-level PCDATA (but does not parse it either). This is not an ideal decision, but it is not clear if a significantly better alternative exists - there are complications with parsing document fragments and parsing valid fragments that do not generate any nodes (i.e. `"<!--comment-->"` without `pugi::parse_comments`).